# Unable to change default selection in streamlit multiselect()

Tags: python, streamlit, python-polars

I am new to `streamlit` apps and facing an **issue** of **not able to select any other `option`** other than **default** option when using `st.multiselect()`. I have also tried `st.selectbox` but faced an issue with that as well.

**Demo web app** link for issue: https://party-crime-record.streamlit.app/

**Web page Code** on github: [Code link](https://github.com/johnsnow09/Party_Criminal_Records/blob/main/1_Analysis_doubt_github.py)

`multiselect` option code chunk starts from **line number: 46**

**Snapshot** of `multiselect` **code chunk** is provided below:

```
with st.sidebar:
    State_List = df.lazy().select(pl.col('State')).unique().collect().to_series().to_list()

    # State_Selected = st.selectbox(label="Select State",
    #                               options = State_List)

    State_Selected = st.multiselect(label="Select State",
                                    options = State_List,
                                    default = ["Uttar Pradesh"], # Delhi West Bengal  
                                    # default = State_List[-1],
                                    max_selections=1
                                       )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Streamlit is going to rerun the whole script every time something happens on the page so you want to think more functional oriented rather than object oriented and then you want those to be decorated with `@st.cache.___` where anything that is serializable (like lists) can be `st.cache.data` and anything that can't (like lazyframes) is `st.cache.resource`.

You also want to think about how the script will run during transitional states. For instance, what does the rest of the script do when the State selector is blank. It seems like streamlit is trying to be smart and autofill your State so you need to explicitly check if State is selected and return nothing if it's not. This is especially the case because you have your state selector as a mutli selection box with a max selection of 1 so for anyone to change the State they first have to make it blank.

As an aside, if you load a file with `scan_parquet` you don't have to call `.lazy()` as it is already lazy.

This seems to work without any calls to `to_pandas` (except for px)

```
import streamlit as st
import polars as pl
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import plotly.express as px


# from: https://youtu.be/lWxN-n6L7Zc
# StreamlitAPIException: set_page_config() can only be called once per app, and must be called as the first Streamlit command in your script.


st.set_page_config(page_title="Election Party Candidate Analysis",
                    layout='wide',
                    initial_sidebar_state="expanded")


############################## GET DATA ##############################
# @st.cache
@st.cache_resource
def get_data():
    df = pl.scan_parquet('https://github.com/johnsnow09/Party_Criminal_Records/raw/main/Elections_Data_Compiled.parquet')
    return df


############################## DATA DONE ##############################



@st.cache_data
def get_state_list():

    return get_data().select('State').unique().collect().to_series().to_list()

@st.cache_data
def get_year_list(state):
    years=(
        get_data()
            .filter(pl.col('State').is_in(state))
            .select(pl.col('Year'))
            .unique().collect().to_series()
            .sort()
            .to_list()
    )
    if len(years)>0:
        return years
    else:
        #I just put something here for quickness you might want something else
        return  [2022]

    


############################## CREATING HEADER ##############################

header_left,header_mid,header_right = st.columns([1,6,1],gap = "large")

with header_mid:
    # https://docs.streamlit.io/library/get-started/create-an-app
    st.title("Party Criminal Records Analysis")

############################## HEADER DONE ##############################





############################## FIRST FILTER STATE ##############################

with st.sidebar:
    # State_Selected = st.selectbox(label="Select State",
    #                               options = State_List)

    State_Selected = st.multiselect(label="Select State",
                                    options = get_state_list(),
                                    default = "Delhi", # Delhi West Bengal  
                                    #default = get_state_list()[-1],
                                    max_selections=1
                                    )
    
############################## FIRST FILTER STATE DONE ##############################





############################## SECOND FILTER YEAR ##############################


    Year_Selected = st.multiselect(label="Select Election Year",
                                    options=get_year_list(State_Selected),
                                    default=get_year_list(State_Selected)[-1])
    
############################## SECOND FILTER YEAR DONE ##############################
    




############################## FILTERED DATA ##############################



    
############################## FILTERED DATA DONE ##############################    





############################## FIRST PLOT ##############################
@st.cache_resource
def make_chart(State_Selected, Year_Selected):
    df_selected = (get_data()
            .filter((pl.col('State').is_in(pl.lit(State_Selected))) &
                    (pl.col('Year').is_in(pl.lit(Year_Selected)))
            )
            .collect()
            )
    if df_selected.height==0:
        return None

    fig_party_crime_sum = px.bar(df_selected.groupby(['Party']
                                ).agg(pl.col('Criminal_Case').sum()
                                ).sort(by='Criminal_Case',descending=True
                                ).head(18).to_pandas(),
                                orientation='h',
                                x='Criminal_Case',y='Party', color="Party",
                                labels={
                                        "Criminal_Case": "Total Criminal Cases",
                                        "Party": "Election Parties"
                                    },
                            
                            title=f'<b>{State_Selected[0]} - Top 18 Election Parties with Total Criminal Records in 2022 Elections</b>')
    # fig_party_crime_sum.update_yaxes(autorange="reversed")
    fig_party_crime_sum.update_layout(title_font_size=26, height = 600, 
                                        showlegend=False
                                        )
    fig_party_crime_sum.add_annotation(
                                        showarrow=False,
                                        text='Data Source: https://myneta.info/',
                                        xanchor='right',
                                        x=2,
                                        xshift=675,
                                        yanchor='bottom',
                                        y=0.01 #,
                                        # font=dict(
                                        #     family="Courier New, monospace",
                                        #     size=22,
                                        #     color="#0000FF"
                                    )
    return fig_party_crime_sum

if make_chart(State_Selected, Year_Selected):
    st.plotly_chart(make_chart(State_Selected, Year_Selected),use_container_width=True)

############################## FIRST PLOT DONE ##############################
```

Comment: thanks for sharing the detailed explanation & the highly optimized code. This is really gonna help me to improve my skills in `streamlit` & `polars`. Really appreciate it :) :)

Comment: np. I hadn't used streamlit before but got really curious why converting things to pandas made it work. It *seems* like streamlit is recognizing a pandas dataframe and can do smart things to act the way you expect but when it sees a polars object, it gets confused without knowing explicitly what to do when inputs are blank.

Comment: well your curiosity really helped me for sure. By the way I have already changed select option from `multiselect` to `singleselect` but my code still needs alot of improvement and with ur addition to the answers I will be able to improve alot of the code. Here is the `streamlit` app that I was working on: - https://indian-party-crime-records.streamlit.app/

Comment: Looks nice. One note, in your chart titles, you should use list joining like `", ".join(Year_Selected)` instead of having the list directly. Better yet make a function that checks

Comment: Thanx, I was actually trying to resolve it in f strings `f'title{*Year_Selected}'` & tried using `*` to unpack the list but that didn't work earlier. But that's a good idea to use `", ".join(Year_Selected)` to take it out of f strings & unpack the list & then join it.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that the lazy `df` is *re-loaded* after each time your try to select another `State`.

Mayeb you need to [`fetch`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/lazyframe/api/polars.LazyFrame.fetch.html#polars.LazyFrame.fetch) the lazy *DataFrame* to use [`to_pandas`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/dataframe/api/polars.DataFrame.to_pandas.html#polars.DataFrame.to_pandas), so you can cache `get_data` ?

```
@st.cache_data
def get_data():
    df = pl.scan_parquet('Elections_Data_Compiled.parquet')
    
    return df.fetch(n_rows=sys.maxsize).to_pandas()

df = get_data()
```

> *Full code* : [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/LMyabnCa)

Output :

[image]

Comment: You are right but this means then I will have to work with `pandas` and cant leverage the `polars` efficiency. I have another webapp:- https://vineet-bse-sample.streamlit.app/One_stock_analysis where I am using the same process & `polars` and when I remove the default option there from the third filter `Security Name` then it let's me select other options too. I think it becomes an issue when its in the first filter

Comment: I think I have figured out the way around it. Thanks to your code I tried to convert only parts of it to `pandas` and figured out that only the **1st multiselect()** `list` need to be converted into `pandas`. So by changing the code at line 49 to `State_List = df.collect().to_pandas()["State"].unique().tolist()` worked and I can still keep polars lazy eval at all other places in the code.

Comment: Great and well done ;)

Answer (score 0):

##### Just by changing the `1st multiselect` filter `to pandas` instead of `polars lazy eval` this worked & also able to keep polars lazy eval at other parts of the code

```
with st.sidebar:
   # Changed below line of code only
   State_List = df.collect().to_pandas()["State"].unique().tolist()

   # State_Selected = st.selectbox(label="Select State",
   #                               options = State_List)

   State_Selected = st.multiselect(label="Select State",
                                options = State_List,
                                default = ["Uttar Pradesh"], # Delhi West Bengal  
                                # default = State_List[-1],
                                max_selections=1
                                   )
```